# Using Angular2 on SharePoint 2013 MasterPage leads to Zone.JS error

Tags: angular, sharepoint-2013, zonejs

i build a small angular2 app. I am referencing the appcomponent directly on a custom sharepoint 2013 masterpage. Its loading correctly but when i am opening the settings menu of the sharepoint
[image: SharePoint Settingsmenue]
i got a "Out of stack space" error in the zone.js part.

```
Zone.prototype.runTask = function (task, applyThis, applyArgs) {
        task.runCount++;
        if (task.zone != this)
            throw new Error('A task can only be run in the zone which created it! (Creation: ' + task.zone.name +
                '; Execution: ' + this.name + ')');
        var previousTask = _currentTask;
        _currentTask = task;
        var oldZone = _currentZone;
        _currentZone = this;
        try {
            if (task.type == 'macroTask' && task.data && !task.data.isPeriodic) {
                task.cancelFn = null;
            }
            try {
                return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            _currentZone = oldZone;
            _currentTask = previousTask;
        }
    };
```

In the catch block the error is catched. After that error a second one occures directly: "Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode".

Following Screenshot shows the error in Firefox console. It occures everytime by hovering an element in the sharepoint settings menue:
[image: Zone.js Error in Firefox]

Any suggestions will be greate.
Thanks for your help, greetings
Anton

Answer (score 0):

This is a name conflict bug , have been fixed here, https://github.com/angular/zone.js/commit/fcd8be52c2e813e5aa91d2239ab28cbc2d04efa7
you can try zone.js 0.78+, it will be OK, I have tested it.